# Is there a function for logging to *Messages* buffer without displaying in the echo-area?

Tags: logging

Is there a function for logging to *Messages* buffer without displaying in the echo-area?  Or maybe another build in log mechanism?

I'm after a kind of console.log("string") kind of functionality.

Comment: Here is a link that demonstrates how I do it:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/6003/2287  Essentially, the function `(messages-buffer)` is used to obtain the buffer or create one with the proper mode if it doesn't exist.  The function -- using `(inhibit-read-only t)` -- goes to the bottom of the buffer and tests to see if it is at a new line, if not then create a new line, then insert the contents of the message (what ever it is), then test again to see if it is a new line, if not at new line then insert one.  This method keeps the echo area available for stuff like interactive prompts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With emacs-snapshot, you can let-bind `inhibit-message` to t:

> Non-nil means calls to `message' are not displayed.
>   They are still logged to the *Messages* buffer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to call `(message "")` immediately after. This will, however, wipe out any existing content in the echo area.

```
(message "foo")
(message "")
```